# Solve the following integral using Stokes Theorem.

Tags: surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am asked to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int\int \text{curl} \ \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$$
where $F = (y,-x,zx^3y^2)$ and $S$ is the surface given by $x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2 = 1$ with $z \leq 0$.

I did not have any problem with any other exercises of this kind. But this one is hard.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with? Have you found the boundary of the surface?

Comment: I am having difficulties with all the exercie. I dont know how to parametrize that boundary. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The surface is the lower half of the ellipsoid, lying below the plane $z = 0$. The boundary lies in that plane. Substitute $z = 0$ into the equation of the ellipsoid.

Comment: So I just parametrize $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and then calculate $F$ over that parametrization?

Comment: Correct, then you integrate $\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf s$.